# Vue-router and dynamic routes nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, dynamic, vue-router, router

I have been using history mode which was working great and used the simple nginx. I have now added dynamic routes so that when a user types baseurl.com/microcosm/anynametheywant - this connects them to that space which works great in local development but when I move to the server I get 404s from this, I have tried a number of things here is current nginx, router/index.js - still doesn't work and still returns the server 404 not even the component help appreciated

NGINX file as it stands

```
server {
    listen 111.111.11.111:80;
    server_name *.nodenogg.in;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location @rewrites {
  rewrite ^(.)$ /index.html last;
}

location ~ /microcosm/\d+$ {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

}
```

router/index.js

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  // dynamic segement `:microcosm` is added to the path
  {
    path: '/microcosm/:microcosm',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
  }

]
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base:   base: process.env.VUE_APP_HTTP + '://' + process.env.VUE_APP_URL + '/',
  routes
})

export default router
```

grabbing and using 
Router.currentRoute.params.microcosm

Comment: Do you get a blank page or a 404 at "http://baseurl.com/microcosm"?  (Default `/` route)

Comment: I get the servers 404 not even my component

Comment: there's no root path set in the Nginx config shown, that may be why it can't find index.html

Comment: can you provide more detail please ? As i have tried 
the line root /var/www/vhosts/nodenogg.in/alpha.nodenogg.in;

Comment: works fine for browsing it's just but when I manualy try to visit the dynamic route  /microcosm/dynamicname I get 404 on build on real server but it works all good on serve on localhost

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the regex, what it's supposed to match?  Have you tested the location without it to make sure it works on a direct hit?

Comment: I do not know whatt the regex does :| however I have tried with less and no matter what anytime i try to manually load /microcosm/anotherword - always 404

Answer (score 0):

Turns out firstly I needed to add to the bottom of my custom nginx and of course I needed to be listening on 443 so it was never being heard and I dont even need the alias thing at this point as I want that to be a 404 and now it is my custom one ! and finally then remove the *.nodenogg.in what a mistake costing me hours !

```
server {

  listen 111.111.11.111:443 ssl;
  server_name alpha.nodenogg.in ssl;
  root /var/www/vhosts/nodenogg.in/alpha.nodenogg.in;

  ssl_certificate /location/ofthekey/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /location/ofthekey/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3;

         location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
         }
 }
```

Comment: thanks @dan for your help to puzzle this out ... https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185093/dan